# show the last employee who was hired

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to find most recent hired employees 
for example i have table

INPUT

```
------------------------
|   name  |  hire_date |
------------------------
| Michael | 11-JAN-2010|
| Eugene  | 20-DEC-2018|
------------------------
```

Need to add third column with '*' in one line with last hired employeer

OUTPUT

```
----------------------------------
|   name  |  hire_date | maxdate |
----------------------------------
| Michael | 11-JAN-2010|         |
| Eugene  | 20-DEC-2018|    *    |
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most recent version of Oracle, use `order by` and `fetch`:

```
select e.*
from employees e
order by hire_date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

In earlier versions, this is often implemented using a subquery:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*
      from employees e
      order by hire_date desc
    ) 
where rownum = 1;
```

Both of these return only one row -- your question is in the singular.  There are variations that return all the most recent employees if there are duplicates.

Comment: but if i had 2 employees hired in one day?

Comment: You are going off from your actual query. Thats the best way Gordon has posted if you want multiple enployees on same date that is most easy step to do just in subquery use max(hiredate) and youll getvwhat you want check my solution

Answer (score 0):

Analytical function might help:

```
SQL> with test (name, hire_date) as
  2    (select 'Michael', date '2010-01-11' from dual union all
  3     select 'Eugene' , date '2018-12-20' from dual
  4    )
  5  select name,
  6         hire_date,
  7         case when rank() over (order by hire_date desc) = 1 then '*' else null end maxdate
  8  from test;

NAME    HIRE_DATE  MAXDATE
------- ---------- -------
Eugene  20-12-2018 *
Michael 11-01-2010

SQL>
```

Yet another option, without analytical function:

```
SQL> with test (name, hire_date) as
  2    (select 'Michael', date '2010-01-11' from dual union all
  3     select 'Eugene' , date '2018-12-20' from dual
  4    ),
  5  maxdate as
  6    (select max(hire_date) max_hire_date
  7     from test
  8    )
  9  select t.name,
 10         t.hire_date,
 11         case when t.hire_date = m.max_hire_date then '*' else null end maxdate
 12  from test t cross join maxdate m;

NAME    HIRE_DATE  MAXDATE
------- ---------- --------
Michael 11-01-2010
Eugene  20-12-2018 *

SQL>
```

Comment: How can i do this without over

Comment: You could compare hire_date column value with maximum value of the same column. I have edited my answer and added some more code. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
     Select hire_date, name from( Select  
       hire_date, name, row_number 
     () over (partition by hire_date order
     by hire_date desc) rn
     from
     Table where hire_date
      =  (select max(hire_date)
      From table)) where rn=1
```